# Which is preferred, 気が遠くなるほど or 気の遠くなるほど?

Tags: meaning, usage, particles, particle-の, particle-が

Considering the expression 気が遠くなるほど to describe something of a large scale or hard to conceive, is the variant 気の遠くなるほど also correct and is there any difference in meaning or nuance? Is there any sort of preference? While the first appears in most dictionaries, I am encountering the second in written form by a native from Osaka.

https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%8C%E9%81%A0%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE

Comment: If you already know ga-no conversion and still want a clarification specific to this phrase for a reason, please explain what made you think they might be different.